# Dropping a level from a factor within a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame 'qlfs' which contains a column 'qlfs$TravelMode'.

The $TravelMode is a factor containing 10 levels:

```
levels(qlfs$TravelMode)
[1] "Non-working adult"                   
[2] "Car,van,minibus,works van"           
[3] "Motorbike,moped,scooter"             
[4] "Bicycle"                             
[5] "Bus,coach,private bus"               
[6] "Taxi"                                
[7] "Railway train"                       
[8] "Underground train,light railway,tram"
[9] "Walk"                                
[10] "Other method"
```

The dataset contains 90k + rows.

I would like to remove level 1 (Non-working adult) and any associated rows from the wider dataframe.

I have tried the following:

```
for (i in 1:NROW(qlfs$TravelMode)) {
   if(qlfs$TravelMode[i]="Non-working adult") {
       qlfs$TravelMode[i] <- "NA"
   }
}
```

Where I would then remove the NAs at a later point, but this did not work.

I have also looked at droplevels() function, but could not get this to work.

Can anybody point out where I am going wrong or suggest a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Try `qlfs_clean <- qlfs[ qlfs$TravelMode != "Non-working adult", ]`

Comment: Once you deleted the rows, like @zx8754 said, then droplevels

Comment: I tried both and could not get this level to drop

Comment: qlfs$TravelMode = factor (qlfs$TravelMode)

Comment: I worked out the issue: the level I was trying to delete still contained entries. I removed the entries by removing the corresponding rows within the dataframe and then running factor(qlfs$TravelMode) which got rid of the now obsolete level. Cheers for your help guys

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the rows you don't want and then recreate the factors.

```
d <- factor(letters[1:20])

d <- d[d != 'a']
d <- factor(d)

levels(d)
```

Comment: Whoops, sorry! I tried this and Non-working adults was still a level

Comment: Then I think we'd need to see a reproducible example.

Comment: I worked out what it was in the end, the factor() function would not work as the level still contained entries. I dropped all rows from the dataframe with the corresponding level and then when the entries were equal to 0 I ran factor() and it dropped the level. Cheers for your help